# How can I make CSS float like auto layout in iOS xcode storyboard?

Tags: ios, xcode, layout, storyboard, css-float

I want to put several image view in a row. And during runtime, I will show/hide the image view dynamically, is there anything I can set in the storyboard so that when one of them is hidden, the rest on its right will "float" to the left to fill its position. In html, I can style all div to float to do so, anything similar in iOS? Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To my knowledge, this is not possible. In CSS, setting an object invisible will (by default) remove it from the layout process. That's not so in iOS, as an object's placement isn't dependent on other objects in the same way. In CSS, it's a left-to-right, top-down engine. In iOS, it's a different issue with shocks and struts and flexible/fixed margins/heights/widths.

To do what you're suggesting, you'd probably have to write your own layout engine, which would (maybe) take an array of UIImageView objects, check each one for its `hidden` property and lay it out or skip (set its `frame` equal to `CGRectZero` or something) as needed. I don't think it would be too difficult to set up this engine, but it will be custom.

Does that answer your question?

Comment: Is this still true as of 2014?

Comment: To my knowledge, opacity still does not affect layout in iOS the way it does in CSS and this has not changed with Auto Layout.